Prove that $3^{271}<7^{153}$
Prove that $3^{271}<7^{153}$.
Approach:
$3^{271}<7^{153}\leftrightarrow \frac{\ln7}{\ln3}>\frac{271}{153}$
$\frac{\ln7}{\ln3}=1.771243\ldots$
$\frac{271}{153}=1.771241\ldots$
Can the inequality be proven without using logarithms? using arithmetic properties or notable inequalities.
Any hint woul be appreciated.

I would be very surprised if someone comes up with proof without much calculation. These two integers are close to each other, they have the same number of digits and the first 3 digits:
\begin{align*}
7^{153} & = 1995262876301749705743355733163350069567511859853733802691255552209426302648784449479340269807714289948321871472250346731193598407 \
3^{271} & = 1994619355373578695983973861244678599884736667898459407831704406497915612809764021038891872427787454834790060356440886952643325547
\end{align*}

You may use $7=6+1=8-1$ to change the inequality into an inequality in terms of $\ln2$ and $\ln 3$.

FWIW, the continued fraction $[1,1,3,2,1,2,4]$ of $271/153$ is the first $7$ terms of the continued fraction of $\log_37$, with the next term in the latter being $22$.

@coiso's method is my recommendation. Note one doesn't need a high-precision decimal expansion of $\log_37$ to check the match, since we can continue the calculation$$\log_37=1+\frac{1}{\log_{7/3}3}=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\log_{9/7}(7/3)}}.$$

@J.G. Is that viable? I didn't check far but my guess is it would get to high enough powers of $3$ and $7$ to be impossible to do by hand. I thought my comment was evidence there is no simple by-hand calculation.

One idea I had was writing $$ \frac{7^{153}}{3^{271}}=\frac{7^{ax+b}}{3^{cx+d}}=\Bigl(1-\frac{3^c-7^a}{3^c}\Bigr)^x\frac{7^b}{3^d}>\Bigl(1-\frac{3^c-7^a}{3^c}x\Bigr)\frac{7^b}{3^d}>1 $$ for a judicious choice of $a,b,c,d,x$. Perhaps someone can write a program to check all possibilities and see if any of them work.

@coiso It might not work by hand, but the level of electronic precision needed in individual calculations will probably be much lower than doing it in the obvious way that doesn't use continued fractions. A lot of software can't use the obvious approach.

$$7^{153}>3^{271}$$
$$153\ln(9-2)>271\ln3$$
$$35\ln3>-153\ln(1-\tfrac29)$$
By using an expansion of $\operatorname{arctanh}x$ for $\ln 3$ and Maclaurin series of $\ln(1-x)$,
$$35\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(2n+1)4^n}>153\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{2^m}{m9^m}$$
and thus it is enough to show that
$$35\sum_{n=0}^6\frac1{(2n+1)4^n}>153\left(\sum_{m=1}^7\frac{2^m}{m9^m}+\frac18\sum_{m=8}^\infty\left(\frac29\right)^m\right)$$
which is true.

Curious, is it a style choice to have that \tfrac there, or was it unintentional?

Parantheses stay smaller, ratio looks bigger when \frac is used. I think. @ultralegend5385

Why not use \left ( ... \right ) to size the parentheses?

@EdmaandVladPhiyik It's a style choice, I also prefer keeping parenthesis vertically small if nothing too interesting is happening in there.

We may write:
$153\times 2=306=307-1\Rightarrow 7^{306}\equiv 1\bmod 307$
$\Rightarrow (7^{153})^2\equiv 1\bmod 307\Rightarrow 7^{153}\equiv 1\bmod 307=a\times 307+1$
$3^{271}\times3^{35}=3^{306}\equiv 1\bmod 307$
$\Rightarrow 3^{271}\equiv \frac 1{3^{35}}\bmod 307=b\times 307 +\frac 1{3^{35}}$
Suppose $7^{153}$ and $3^{271}$ are so close that in dividing them by $307$ the integer part of the quotients are equal and the difference is in decimal part, i.e $a=b$ then we compare theses relations:
$7^{153}=a\times 307+1$
$3^{271}=b\times 307 +\frac 1{3^{35}}$
Which deduces that:
$7^{153}>3^{271}$

How can you suppose that?
